# Compressing a file multiple no. of times using gzip command in linux

Tags: linux

I am working in linux and I want to gzip a file multiple no. of times. But after first compression, the .gz file cannot be compressed further. Is there a way to gzip that file further?

Comment: You do understand that you will get basically no benefit from compressing a compressed file? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: It is a futile effort in vastly diminishing returns.

Comment: if you can compress further than the compression tool is a wastage of money...

Comment: @John3136 i understand further compression will after a certain point(or perhaps after the first time) will only increase the size of the compressed file. But there is a certain function that i want to see if it can detect multiple compression of a file. So can it be done?

Comment: People you are killing me by downvoting the question and not answering it.....:')

Comment: @BrainsOfSteel Rather than asking how to compress a file more, explain the problem. Why do you need to compress it more. There may be a better solution, since compression can only do so much

Answer (score 4):

```
$ gzip < hello > hello.gz
$ gzip < hello.gz > hello.gz.gz
$ gzip < hello.gz.gz > hello.gz.gz.gz
$ ls -l hello*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 radams radams 792 Aug 16 00:37 hello
-rw-rw-r-- 1 radams radams  34 Aug 16 02:42 hello.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 radams radams  55 Aug 16 02:42 hello.gz.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 radams radams  78 Aug 16 02:42 hello.gz.gz.gz
```